# Changing div height according screen resolution javascript

Tags: javascript, css, styles, height

Here is the problem. I have

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

I want to check user resolution and change his height according user resolution, using javascript?

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var height = screen.height
    document.getElementById(main).style.height = height;
};
```

I even try this:

```
window.onload = function() { 
    var height = screen.height 
    var ele = document.getElementById(main);
    if(ele.style.height == "auto") 
    {
            ele.style.height = height;
    }
    else {
        ele.style.height = height;
    }
};
```

Comment: Post up what you've got so far in terms of JavaScript

Comment: try this `height:auto;`

<div style="height:auto;" id="main"></div>

Comment: window.onload = function()
                {
var height = screen.height
document.getElementById(main).style.height = height;

                };

Comment: Not working solution? I dont see why?

Comment: This question needs more context... Why do you want to do it with javascript? What is contained within #main? Is there anything else on the page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=div+height+%5Bjavascript%5D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want set the Screen Height:

```
var mainNode = document.getElementById("main");
mainNode.style.height = screen.height + "px";
```

[Screen Avail Height](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_availheight.asp)

[Screen Height](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_height.asp)

[DOMElement Client Height](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp)

Screen height is different from client height (document.documentElement.clientHeight).

Comment: Thanks this works great, the problem was with string "px", thanks again

Comment: Just little, help, how can i add more 40px on user height screen resolutin?

Comment: mainNode.style.height = (screen.height + 40) + "px";