# Adding more scroll to smaller resolution

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am creating an application to work on different resolutions, and I have a dashboard page but because I have a footer bar on my page for the higher resolution its fine but for the smaller resolution the footer bar is getting in the way of the items, I will try and show an example:

Higher Res:

[image]

Where the red line is is the bottom of my items, but now I will show my smaller res

[image]

As you can see the footer bar is in the way and there isn't enough scroll on the page to see the bottom of my items.

I have tried setting the body to have a bigger height which does work, but then creates a scroll bar on the higher res and I don't want that.

Here is what I tried:

```
body {
    Height: 125%;
}
```

and this is my footer code:

```
.bsimplex-footer-bar{
     width:100%;
     bottom:0;
     position:fixed;
     margin-right:10px;
     background-color:#6a3d98;
     margin-left:-10px;
     height: 41px; 
     display: flexbox; 
     display: -ms-flexbox;
}
```

Comment: show some code .. what you tried?

Comment: @Kiran I have posted my footer bar code and also the height of the body code i tried.

Comment: did you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855116/changing-div-height-according-screen-resolution-javascript.. hope this will help you

Comment: @Kiran Is there not just a way to make the footer relative? but stick to the bottom of the page? is should move down then?

Comment: can you create a fiddle? so that we can understand your problem and try to solve it